# Browser Activity not working

Tags: android, browser, monkeyrunner

I need to launch the browser in the device.

The android version is 4.1

The line below isn't working, It's written in monkeyrunner

```
device.startActivity( component='com.google.android.browser/.BrowserActivity', uri=url)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
PACKAGE = 'com.android.browser'
ACTIVITY = '.BrowserActivity'
COMPONENT = PACKAGE + "/" + ACTIVITY
URI = 'www.google.com'
device.startActivity(component=COMPONENT, uri=URI)
```

Answer (score 1):

To open a URL/website you do the following:

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: is this applicable in monkeyrunner?